# CodeIgniter - Keep input value after clicking pagination

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pagination

I have `input type = "date"` that allows user to pick a date range to run the query and show in table. But however, when I click `Page 2` from the pagination , the date value lost, and the query does not search with the dates picked. How should I do to keep the value for query to run `WHERE` clause.

My Controller:

```
public function searchDate()
{   

   $this->load->library('session');
     if ($this->input->post('search')) { 
     $this->session->set_userdata('search' , $this->input->post('search'));
   }
   $orders=new ReportModel;

   $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "/Report/searchDate";
   $config["total_rows"] = $orders->record_count_search();
   $config["per_page"] = 150;
   $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
   $config["num_links"] = 10;
   $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
   $config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;

   $this->pagination->initialize($config);
   $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

   $data['data']=$orders->get_orders_search($config["per_page"], $page);
   $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

   $this->load->view('includes/header');
   $this->load->view('estoreReport/list',$data);
   $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

My View:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="search" action="<?php echo base_url('estoreReport/searchDate')?>" method = "post">
            <div class="form-group">

              <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Order Date From" name = "searchDateFrom" value="<?php echo set_value('searchDateFrom') ?>" >
              <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Order Date To" name = "searchDateTo" max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"  value="<?php echo set_value('searchDateTo') ?>" >                    
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default " type="submit" value = "search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </form>
```

I've tried to use `session` in my controller but it seems not working though.

```
$this->load->library('session');
 if ($this->input->post('search')) { 
 $this->session->set_userdata('search' , $this->input->post('search'));
```

}

Please help, thanks. I am a very new CI learner.

Comment: If you are pagination, its better to use GET method, so that search factors will be in url .

Comment: @Rafee can I know how to modify my code to use get method ?

Comment: https://www.formget.com/pagination-in-codeigniter/
look for more examples in google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `GET` instead of `POST` so that your pagination link have your search date value on it.
At your View just change your method to `GET`

> method = "get"

At your model where you get the value of your input, also change the method to `GET`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookie for your task. [Official codeigniter cookie docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/cookie_helper.html)

To set cookie use:

```
$cookie=  ['name'   => 'date',
           'value'  => $dateValue,                            
           'expire' => '1000',                                                                                   
           'secure' => TRUE];
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

To get cookie use:

```
$this->input->cookie('date',true);
```

And to delete cookie use:

```
delete_cookie('date');
```

Or better to use get request and send date as param.

Comment: could u please help on my code of how to modify it ?